# Conditional count of rows between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have the following 2 dataframes:

```
machine_id  time_to_failure
430494        1000
430494        700
430494        500
430494        100
430495        1000
430495        200

machine_id    event
430494        100
430494        600
430495        500
430495        100
```

I would like to add a third 'count' column to my first df that counts the number of rows in the second df that has `event < time_to_failure`. Sample output:

```
machine_id  time_to_failure  Count
430494        1000             2
430494        700              2
430494        500              1
430494        100              0
430495        1000             2
430495        200              1
```

How do I do this without iterating through the rows? I tried:

```
df1.insert(len(df1.columns), "Count", df2.loc[(df1.machine_id == df2.machine_id) &
                                              (df1.time_to_failure > df2.event)].count() )
```

But I received the error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I've already tried resetting the indexes and checking object types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea with broadcasting with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), select another `DataFrame`, compare and sum `True`s values for count:

```
def f(x):
    y = df2.loc[df2['machine_id'].eq(x.name), 'event']
    return (x.to_numpy()[:, None] > y.to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)
    
df1['Count'] = df1.groupby('machine_id')['time_to_failure'].transform(f)
print (df1)
   machine_id  time_to_failure  Count
0      430494             1000      2
1      430494              700      2
2      430494              500      1
3      430494              100      0
4      430495             1000      2
5      430495              200      1
```

Comment: How to extend this to matching multiple columns instead of a single machine_id?

Comment: @Sample_friend - Can you be more specific?

Comment: Let's say I have another column location_id. How to do the same counting exercise but we must now match both location_id and machine_id.

Comment: @Sample_friend - Then change `df1['Count'] = df1.groupby(['machine_id','location_id'])['time_to_failure'].transform(f)` and `y = df2.loc[df2['machine_id'].eq(x.name[0]) & df2['location_id'].eq(x.name[1]), 'event']`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll wait around to see if anyone else has another approach before accepting this answer.

Comment: @Sample_friend - sure, wait some time ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223140/discussion-between-sample-friend-and-jezrael).